# How to save a viewpager content contained in a fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I use a master/detail flow and in every fragment I have a `viewpager` containing some forms but the thing is when I click on some other links from the master list, the content of the `viewpager` is lost. How to save this content so everytime I click on the same choice I find my data.
My code :

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(String id) {
        if (mTwoPane) {
            // In two-pane mode, show the detail view in this activity by
            // adding or replacing the detail fragment using a
            // fragment transaction.

            if(id.contains("1"))
            {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

                ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
                fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
            }
            else if(id.contains("2"))
            {
                Bundle arguments = new Bundle();

                ItemDetailFragment2 fragment = new ItemDetailFragment2();
                fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
                fragment.setArguments(arguments);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, fragment).commit();
            }
        } else {
            // In single-pane mode, simply start the detail activity
            // for the selected item ID.
            Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, ItemDetailActivity.class);
            detailIntent.putExtra(ItemDetailFragment.ARG_ITEM_ID, id);
            startActivity(detailIntent);
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I tried to modify my code this way :

```
if (id.contains("1")) {
Fragment currFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(lastTag);

                ItemDetailFragment newFragment = (ItemDetailFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("f"+1);
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

                ft.hide(currFragment);

                    if(newFragment==null)
                    {lastTag="f"+1;

                    newFragment=new ItemDetailFragment();
                    ft
                    .replace(R.id.item_detail_container, newFragment);}
                    else {
                        ft.show(newFragment);
                    }


                ft.commit();
}
```

But i got a `NullPointerException` at `android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackrecord.java:656)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to call setRetainInstance(true) in your fragments onCreate()

As writed [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html#Replace), if you do not add the transaction to the back stack, then the fragment is destroyed when removed or replaced.
You can hide current fragment, instead replacing, then add new. Like that:

```
int currPage = 0;

public void goToPage(int num) {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("f" + currPage);
    Fragment newFragment = fm.findFragmentByTag("f" + num);
    FragmentTransition ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    ft.hide(currFragment);

    if(newFragment == null) {
        // First use. Create new instance for page.
        newFragment = new MyFragment();
        ft.add(R.id.item_detail_container, newFragment, "f" + num);
    } else {
        // Fragment for page already added. Just show it.
        ft.show(newFragment);
    }

    ft.commit();
    this.currPage = num;
}
```

And don't forget to specify tag for initial page fragment too.

Comment: I actually called the setRetainInstance(true) in every fragment containing a viewpager but how to call the instance back?

Comment: Strange. Can you write the code, how you replacing detail fragments?

Comment: It's just sample. You can edit your onItemSelected to do same work.

Comment: I tried your solution and i got the nullPointerException in the line 
ft.add(R.id.item_detail_container, newFragment, "f" + num);

Comment: I checked this code, and it works ok for me. How you place initial page fragment? And why you use replace method without tag in your updated question? In this case you can't use findFragmentByTag()

Comment: Yeah i replaced it with Add,but the problem now is I don't know which one the user wil choose first so how can i initialize each time?

Comment: I finally found a way to make it work but it if i change the orientation of the device it doesn't work anymore

Comment: Orientation change is different question. There are two solutions for this: you can add android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" attribute to your AndroidManifest.xml(best solution if you have one design for all orientations), or save your fragments in onPause method with FragmentManager.putFragment() method, and restore it with FragmentManager.getFragment() at onRestore()

Answer (score 0):

It's better to save in the arrayList. Onclick store the image id in the arrayList.

Comment: Can you develop more your answer please, didn't get it

Comment: I want to say, every time you click on the image store it  and so when you click o other link and come back you can retry from stored images

Comment: There is no images, in every viewpager there is forms so i don't want to loose the data

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the `onPause()` or `onStop()` methods of your fragments and save the data when that methods are called, which happens automatically when they are removed.

Or you could perhaps go with the savedInstanceState.

Comment: I usually use the savedInstanceState but I don't know how to do it with the fragment and containg viewpager which make things a bit complicated